# Possible to open subtab with notificationsLibrary showToast()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
({
        handleShowToast : function(component, event, helper) {
                component.find('notifLib').showToast({
                "title": "Success!",
                "message": "Record {0} created! See it {1}!",
                "messageData": [
                    'Salesforce',
                    {
                        url: '/a1KFg000000096YMAQ',
                        label: 'here',
                    }
                ]
            });
        })
```

Doing this opens the record in a new tab. Is it possible to specify opening as subtab to the current tab?